# Were there any enhancement chips that vastly outperformed the main CPU?

Tags: hardware, chip, game-cartridge, microprocessor, game-consoles

Were there any enhancement chips in officially-released games that were CPUs themselves and which ran the game code itself, relegating the role of the main CPU to that of a thin client?

To elaborate, I'm only asking about enhancement chips that themselves were microprocessors and which executed game code *on their own*. This excludes many popular chips like [MMC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_controller) and [SuperFX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_FX) which were slaved to the CPU in the console and did not fetch and run code independently.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135288/discussion-on-question-by-forest-were-there-any-enhancement-chips-that-vastly-ou).

Comment: The super gameboy basically had a gameboy inside, so that had its own cpu and relegated the snes' cpu to a thin client like what you're asking after. It's not quite a game on its own though because it needs a gameboy game still to play, so I'm not sure if it's what you're looking for or not

Comment: I can't find details on this right now, which is why this is a comment, but there was a Go game sold on cartridge for a console (SNES? GBA?) that used a significantly more powerful ARM chip for the AI.

Comment: Hayazashi Nidan: Morita Shougi 2 allegedly has a  21.47 MHz, 32-bit ARMv3 chip in it, according to Wikipedia, from an now-dead site; another website says it was never sold.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I think the SA-1 chip in various late-era Super Nintendo cartridges (eg. Kirby Super Star, Kirby's Dream Land 3, Super Mario RPG) would qualify.

Here's what [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Super_NES_enhancement_chips#SA1) has to say about it (emphasis mine):

> Similar to the 5A22 CPU in the Super NES hardware, the SA1 contains a processor core **based on the 65C816** with several programmable timers.[2] **The SA1 does not function as a slave CPU for the 5A22; both can interrupt each other independently.**
>
> The SA1 also features a range of enhancements over the standard 65C816:
>
> - **10.74 MHz clock speed, compared to the 5A22's maximum of 3.58 MHz**
> - Faster RAM, **including 2 KB of internal RAM**
> - **Memory mapping capabilities**
> - Limited data storage and compression
> - New DMA modes such as bitmap to bit plane transfer
> - Arithmetic functions (multiplication, division, and cumulative)
> - **Hardware timer (either as a linear 18-bit timer, or synchronised with the PPU to generate an IRQ at a specific H/V scanline location)**
> - Built-in CIC lockout, for copy protection and regional marketing control

So every cartridge with an SA-1 chip essentially has an independent SoC in it, clocked at three times the speed of the SNES's main CPU.

Answer (score 12):

Not quite what you're looking for, but if you bought a first generation Mac and a LaserWriter printer to go with it, your printer had more horsepower than your computer.

Comment: Printers are also where you can train writing malar in FORTH ...

Comment: Because the LaserWriter had a 12 MHz 68000, versus the 8 MHz 68000 in the Macintosh? Maybe you could add some more details/specifics of this type to your answer?

Comment: Going back a little further, our RML380Z had a 4MHz Z80A while the 9-pin dot matrix printer boasted a 6MHz Z80B